Validation password fail android studio even after using same chara
I just complete creating feature for creating account in my apps. My problem now i get error when compare password and re-password although using same chara. Here screenshot from my emulator:

for my button code:
btn_kirim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            user = ed_username.getText().toString();
            email = ed_email.getText().toString();
            pass = String.valueOf(ed_pass.getEditText().getText());
            repass = String.valueOf(ed_repass.getEditText().getText());
            createAccount(user, email, pass, repass, database,fAuth);
        }
    });

Here part for validation :
private void createAccount(String user, String pass, String repass, String email, DatabaseReference database2, FirebaseAuth fAuth) {
    if (user.isEmpty() || pass.isEmpty() || repass.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Data belum lengkap",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (!pass.equals(repass)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Password tidak sama",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(CreateAccountPage.this, "Register Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(CreateAccountPage.this, "Error!!" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        //Menambahkan data ke real-time database firebase
        database2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        database2.child(user).child("username").setValue(user);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Register berhasil",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(CreateAccountPage.this, LoginPage.class));
    }
}

for xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".userinterface.CreateAccountPage"
android:background="@drawable/linear_gradient_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_rumah_pucuk"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,MissingConstraints" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Masukkan email anda"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,VisualLintBounds" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed_email_from_create_acc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:hint="Contoh : andy@gmail.com"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:autofillHints="username"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColorHint="#1B5E20"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,TextFields,VisualLintTextFieldSize" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Masukkan username anda"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,VisualLintBounds" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed_username_from_create_acc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:autofillHints="username"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColorHint="#1B5E20"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,TextFields,VisualLintTextFieldSize" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Masukkan password anda"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,VisualLintBounds" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_textPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_password_from_create_acc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="text"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Masukkan kembali password anda"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,VisualLintBounds" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_textRepassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_repassword_from_create_acc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="text"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<Space
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back_from_create_acc"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kembali"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_kirim_from_create_acc"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kirim"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</LinearLayout>

Is there any wrong with my code especially for validating password part?

Did you debug your code to actually check that pass and repass are  actually equal?

I just testing it without run in debug mode

Check whether there are no whitespaces within compared strings.

You passed the wrong value in createAccount.
You passed the email as second argument while it should be the pass variable
createAccount(user, email, pass, repass, database,fAuth);

private void createAccount(String user, String pass, String repass, String email, DatabaseReference database2, FirebaseAuth fAuth);


How foolish i am. I already change it and it's work sir, thank you.
